# What misspellings / typos are supported in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What misspellings / typos are supported in Python?

Not alternate spellings such as `is_dir` vs `isdir`, nor `color` vs `colour` but actual wrongly spelt aliases, such as `proprety` for `property` (which isn't supported).

Comment: Someone voted to close as too broad - I disagree: I suspect the current answer has the only supported misspelling in the language/stdlib... and if there are a few others, I would like to know what they are.

Comment: This has been talked about to death (resurrected, then killed again, etc.) on python-dev, but what `mock` is doing seems like a very special case - normally a typo will cause a loud failure when executed, but in the case of `'mock`, it causes a silent error (of sorts). There's far less reason to "support" a typo anywhere else in the stdlib because it will be far more obvious when the typo's been made. For that reason it's not surprising that it's probably the only case where a typo is treated in a special way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Python 3.5 beta 3 the [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) object now supports `assret` standing in for `assert` -- note that this is not the keyword `assert`, but any attribute of a mock object that matches the regular expression `assert.*` or `assret.*`.

Some explanation:

When a mock object is created the default for any attribute access is to return a new `Mock`, except in one case:  if the attribute is one of `assert_called_with`, `assert_called_once_with`, `assert_any_call`, `assert_has_calls`, and `assert_not_called`, in which case some code is actually run.

The problem is if one forgets the exact name and uses, for example, `assert_called`, then instead of code running to check that the mock was called, a new mock is returned instead and the test one wrote passes instead of actually doing the test and possibly failing.

To combat this problem `Mock` now raises an `AttributeError` if any access is made to an attribute that starts with `assert`.

Besides `assert`, `Mock` will also raise an `AttributeError` if any access is made to an attribute that starts with `assret`.

If one does not want the extra protection (for `assert` and `assret`) one can use `unsafe=True` when creating the `Mock`.